# how to assign values into a 2D vector like a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, variable-assignment

Is there anyway to do it? Currently I use like this:

```
for( i=0;i<PU_number;i++)
{
    for( j=0;j<=time_slots;j++)
        myMatrix.tempVec.push_back(0.0);
    myMatrix.value.push_back(myMatrix.tempVec);
    myMatrix.tempVec.clear();
}
```

However, it is not useful for me. Sometimes I need to change a particular adress in this vector. like `myMatrix.tempVec[1][4]`. When I do it like this:

```
myMatrix.value[i][j]=value;
```

it corrupts memory, I get `SIGABRT`, `SIGSESV` and lots of thing like them. Also valgrind gets crazy when I do that. But I need an appropriate way to do it.

EDIT: I did what you guys said:

```
myMatrix.value.resize(PU_number);
for( i=0;i<PU_number;i++)
    myMatrix.value[i].resize(time_slots);
```

and then:

```
for( i=0;i<PU_number;i++)
{
    for( j=0;j<time_slots;j++)
    {
        for( k=0;k<number_of_packets;k++)
        {
            double r=((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
                for( x=myMatrix.mat[i][k];x<=myMatrix.mat[i][k]+myMatrix.len[i][k];x++)
                myMatrix.value[i][x]=r;

        }
    }
}
```

And I got "Invalid write of size 8" again in valgrind.

Comment: Props for using valgrind. Start by fixing what it identifies.

Comment: @WhozCraig It just does not accept the method I have said above. It says "invalid write of size 8" lots of times.

Comment: @Whcrs Your _`for( x=myMatrix.mat[i][k];x<=myMatrix.mat[i][k]+myMatrix.len[i][k];x++)`_ loop doesn't make much sense for me.

Comment: I know. it is difficult to understand. Even I don't remember what I did :) But I can tell you that, when I use the very first method I have told in the original message, I get no error in valgrind. I just remember, it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [`std::vector::resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) function, that can be used to set the dimensions of your *matrix* properly, before you access any values by indexing.

Here's a small sample

```
myMatrix.resize(PU_number);
for( i=0;i<PU_number;i++) {
    myMatrix[i].resize(time_slots);
    for( j=0;j<=time_slots;j++)
        myMatrix[i][j] = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Is it let me assign values like a 2D array?

Comment: @Whcrs It enables you to set the size of the vectors beforhand. Read the linked reference documentation.

Comment: I know that. And I did it now. Valgrind got crazy again.

Comment: Thank you man. I solved it. But stay tune, I think after an half an hour, I will have to pass this `struct`  to another source file in the project. `extern` thing you know :))

Answer (score 2):

You can use a std::vector >
like here :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<int> > vec;
  vec.resize(10);
  for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    {
      vec[i].resize(10);
    }
  vec[1][4] = 3;
  vec[1].push_back(5)
  std::cout << "vec[1][4] = " << vec[1][4] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "vec[1][10] = " << vec[1][10] << std::endl;
  return (0);
}
```

I create a vector of size 10 which contain others vector of size 10;
note that you have to use resize to get the size with a std::vector > but after if you want to add a size you can use vec[i].push_back(5);

Comment: `vec[1][10]` accesses out of bounds.

Comment: no because push_bask will add 1. I tried it because answer it's work